# Common Protocol Property Initialization Similar to Abstract Classes

Tags: swift

The general consensus for abstract class behavior in Swift seems to lean towards using protocols and protocol extensions. This works well to avoid "fatalError" cruft and access control conventions of subclasses. One case I'm struggling with here, though, is how to initialize protocol properties consistently for all conforming classes. For example, an id field I might want to init consistently as a UUID, or a date field I might want to init consistently as an ISO date string.  Is this possible with protocol properties and extensions, or is this a use case that requires class inheritance?

Comment: Sounds like you just haven't used the right type to represent those things. If you use `UUID` for the UUID, and create your own `ISODate` type, then you can allow the property to have only valid values.

Comment: @Sweeper That's fair given my examples. What if we take types out of this and just assume that my business logic has some custom string format for the id. Rather than relying on a custom type implementation here, I'm wondering on whether this is achievable in the protocol/extension.

Comment: Well in any case, you wouldn't want to validate the format only during initialisation, right? You want it to have a valid format at all times, right? That's when you should use your own custom type, regardless of whether you are simulating an abstract class or not.

Comment: I see your point. Let's take another example, then, where I want to have a "creationDate" field initialized to the current time on creation. I don't want conforming classes to choose the date to provide here. A date object would be valid at all times. Would you reach for a custom date type here that handles init to current datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on initialisation here is kind of weird. Surely you would want your properties to have a valid format not just when they are initialised, but *at all times*? This should be the case regardless of whether you are trying to simulate an abstract class or not.

So leaving initialisation aside, I suspect that this is a case of not choosing the appropriate type for your properties. If you use the `UUID` type in Foundation for example, then every value that your property can have will be a valid UUID. There isn't a type that is "ISO 8601 date strings", so you'd need to create that on your own, but I would recommend handling dates as `Date`s or `DateComponent`s, and formatting them as strings only when you need it.

---

There is one big problem with your idea of forcing protocol conformers to initialise properties. The idea of "initialising" a property presumes that the property is implemented as a stored property, e.g.

```
var foo: Int
```

but properties in protocols totally does not need to be stored properties. Implementations have every right to implement protocol properties as computed properties instead. You can't "initialise" something like:

```
var foo: Int {
    get { SomeOtherClass.property }
    set { SomeOtherClass.property = newValue }
}
```

can you? There is no way of stopping anyone from implementing the property this way.

In the comments you also mentioned the scenario of:

> I want to have a "creationDate" field initialized to the current time on creation. I don't want conforming classes to choose the date to provide here.

That's imposing an implementation on the protocol conformers, and protocols should not do that. That's not what protocols are for. Protocols are supposed to declare what members a type should have, not what they are initialised to.

You can get kind of close with an `InitialisedToNow` type.

```
struct InitialisedToNow {
    let date: Date = .now
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    var creationDate: InitialisedToNow { get }
}

struct Implementation: MyProtocol {
    let creationDate = InitialisedToNow()
}
```

But this can be cheated in a few ways, as mentioned before, this requires the property to be a stored property - the moment someone declares a computed `creationDate`, the code breaks:

```
struct Implementation {
    var creationDate: InitialisedToNow { .init() }
}
```

Or if the implementor used a static constant:

```
struct Implementation: MyProtocol {
    static let staticDate = InitialisedToNow()
    let creationDate = Implementation.staticDate
}
```